# Mounting disk-drive using Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, mount

I am trying to write a Python script which mounts and open my folder.
But I have " Could not find "/media/New Volume". " error.
If I mount at first and run the script , it works, opens my New Volume.
But if I don't mount and run it, I get error.

```
sudo python mount.py
```

my changed script

```
import os
import subprocess

if os.path.ismount("/media/New Volume"):
    subprocess.Popen(["nautilus", "/media/New Volume"])
else:
    path = "/media/New Volume"
    os.mkdir(path);
    subprocess.Popen(["mount","-t","fuseblk","/dev/sda4","/media/New Volume"])
    subprocess.Popen(["nautilus", "/media/New Volume"])
```

Comment: Just checking, you are sure that the directory `/mnt/New Volume` is created, right? Keep in mind that `mount` does not creates it by itself.

Comment: The `mount` command does not look good anyway. The syntax should be `mount -t <file system type> <device> <directory>`.

Comment: you also usually need root permissions to mount

Comment: It would be better to use the [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) function instead of constructing `subprocess.Popen` objects directly.  The `check_call` function will raise an exception on a non-zero exit code, and when you're interacting with the environment like this you will want to be handling those exceptional cases.  It will also wait for the called process to terminate, which you definitely want as mounting filesystems can take time (to avoid Nautilus opening first and failing).

Comment: Old question, but for future adventures. Take a look at [mount.py](https://github.com/MrVallentin/mount.py).

Answer (score -1):

If your volume is really called `New Volume` then you might want to consider typing it into your script as `New\ Volume` to escape the space between the words. Otherwise, the linux shell will not recognize it as a connected path and try to append `Volume` as an addition to the command issued before...

Comment: By default (and in this case) the argument list is not processed by the shell and so any such escaping would be redundant.  If the optional argument `shell=True` were specified and the parameter were a string, then this would be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am just used to mount things in the shell directly and thought `call` passes the command to shell...